# How is Errai able to serialize/deserialize model entities

Tags: java, json, gwt, errai

I'm trying to use Errai rest capabilities in my GWT app,
I took a look at the following guide:
http://errai-blog.blogspot.it/2011/10/jax-rs-in-gwt-with-errai.html

In particular, it says:

> We simply put this interface somewhere in our client packages (e.g.
>   client.shared) where the GWT compiler can find it. To create a request
>   all that needs to be done is to invoke RestClient.create()

I think there's a plot hole here, how is Errai able to know how serialize/deserialize model classes ?

Can you help understanfing this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to `RestClient` Class's create() method

```
 public static <T, R> T create(final Class<T> remoteService, final RemoteCallback<R> callback, Integer... successCodes) {
   return create(remoteService, null, callback, null, successCodes);
}
```

In example which you've provided; when using create() method Errai gets the CustomerService Class as `remoteService`, After many operations;

Errai parses and implements this CustomerService Interface with using their [errai-codegen](https://github.com/errai/errai/tree/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-codegen) library which uses [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

When parsing simply;

- First it looks for JAX-RS annotated methods and defines them as
  [JaxrsResourceMethod](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-jaxrs/errai-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/enterprise/rebind/JaxrsResourceMethod.java)
- Then it looks into parameters of that method if there is any parameter that annontated with JAX-RS annotations.
- If it finds annontated parameters in [JaxrsResourceMethod](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-jaxrs/errai-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/enterprise/rebind/JaxrsResourceMethod.java), it keeps that parameter with it's annotation type
- If it finds not annontated parameter in [JaxrsResourceMethod](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-jaxrs/errai-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/enterprise/rebind/JaxrsResourceMethod.java) it defines as a **entityParameter**
- Errai holds these annotated parameter and entityParameters  in [JaxrsResourceMethodParameters](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-jaxrs/errai-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/enterprise/rebind/JaxrsResourceMethodParameters.java) by their method. When building request it uses parameters by their rule.

Let me explain these rules with using an example you've provided.

```
Customer customer = new Customer("new name", "new last name", "new postal code");
RestClient.create(CustomerService.class, callback).updateCustomer(240193, customer);
```

Errai will create url like

> example.com/cusomers/240193

Because @PathParam("id") annotation rule is adding parameter to the url and according to Errai's entityParameter rule `customer` will be marshalled when sending data with PUT.

```
@PUT 
@Path("/{id}") 
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json") 
public Customer updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") long id, Customer customer); //- See more at: http://errai-blog.blogspot.com.tr/2011/10/jax-rs-in-gwt-with-errai.html#sthash.2GTQtIg8.dpuf
```

One more additional note if you check [here](https://github.com/errai/errai/blob/e1f27acd0fc18772ea486e9f8bcfeff2d8267f1b/errai-jaxrs/errai-jaxrs-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/errai/enterprise/rebind/JaxrsResourceMethodParameters.java#L207) there is an exception in setEntityParameter method;

> Only one non-annotated entity parameter allowed per method:

This means you cant define methods with more than 1 non-annotated parameter in Class which you sent in Errai.